# Cron job to run on second friday of Jan and June every year

Tags: cron

I need to schedule a cron job on second Friday of every January and June. I was able to do it for a certain month but I am looking for a way to do it for two different months.

Here is what I have tried:

```
0 0 0 ? 1-6/6 6#2
```

Comment: Can you post what you did so far? It's easier to help you modify it than to think it over from zero.

Comment: @Eduardo Trápani  I have updated the question with what I tried. cron emulator show this one as invalid

Answer (score 2):

Set up a `cron` job to run every Friday in January and June, from the 1st to the 14th:

```
23 9 1-14 Jan,Jun Fri /home/george/bin/do_it
```

In the `do_it` script, `exit` if this is the first Friday

```
daynum=$(date +%e)
[[ $daynum -le 7 ]] && exit
```

On further consideration of the data (2nd Friday is day # 8-14 AND is a Friday) wouldn't this work?

```
23 9 8-14 Jan,Jun Fri /home/george/bin/do_it
```

Comment: This would run the script on the defined days _and_ on every Friday. You could use `*` in the day field and check if both `[ $daynum -ge 8 ] && [ $daynum -le 14 ]` are valid (or invert it and exit).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27813585/cron-expression-to-run-every-6-months-and-on-second-friday-of-the-month.  —> solution in this link helped